# creating html overly with javascript in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, overlay

I am working on a chrome extension that takes selected text and uses that text as a param in  an api request. I have a popup.html file which calls popup.js and this works as intended for the popup.

The requirement is to have the results display as an overlay where the word is selected and not as a popup from the chrome extension icon.

I have managed to get the overlay to display the highlighted text, but i am struggling with getting the overlay to build the html.

I think if i am able to build the html then i should be able to enter the selected text into the api and link each item to the id.

Attached is the content.js file that displays the over lay and then the code that I am wanting built or something like that.

content.js

```
// Add bubble to the top of the page.
var bubbleDOM = document.createElement('div');
bubbleDOM.setAttribute('class', 'selection_bubble');
bubbleDOM.setAttribute('id', 'bubble_id');



document.body.appendChild(bubbleDOM);

// Lets listen to mouseup DOM events.
document.addEventListener(
  'mouseup',
  function(e) {
    var selection = window.getSelection().toString();


    if (selection.length > 0) {

      selection = selection + ' this is some text';

      renderBubble(e.clientX, e.clientY, selection);
    }
  },
  false
);

// Close the bubble when we click on the screen.
document.addEventListener(
  'mousedown',
  function(e) {
    bubbleDOM.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  },
  false
);

// Move that bubble to the appropriate location.
function renderBubble(mouseX, mouseY, selection) {
  bubbleDOM.innerHTML = selection;
  bubbleDOM.style.top = mouseY + 'px';
  bubbleDOM.style.left = mouseX + 'px';
  bubbleDOM.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

code i am trying to write

```
<div>
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title" id="supplier1"></h5>
        <p class="card-text"><span id="city1"></span>, <span id="state1"></span> <span id="country1"></span></p>
        <p class="card-text" >DUNS# <span id="duns1"></span></p>
        <p class="card-text" >CEO: <span id="ceo1"></span></p>
        <!-- <a href="https://test-kys.live.beroeinc.com/confirm/${ceo1}" class="btn btn-primary">Risk Report</a> -->
        <a id="riskReport1" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Risk Report</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title" id="supplier2"></h5>
        <p class="card-text"><span id="city2"></span>, <span id="state2"></span> <span id="country2"></span></p>
        <p class="card-text">DUNS# <span id="duns2"></span></p>
        <p class="card-text">CEO: <span id="ceo2"></span></p>
        <a id="riskReport2" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Risk Report</a>
      </div>
    <div>
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title" id="supplier3"></h5>
        <p class="card-text"><span id="city3"></span>, <span id="state3"></span> <span id="country3"></span></p>
        <p class="card-text">DUNS# <span id="duns3"></span></p>
        <p class="card-text">CEO: <span id="ceo3"></span></p>
        <a id="riskReport3" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Risk Report</a>
      </div>
      <div>
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title" id="supplier4"></h5>
        <p class="card-text"><span id="city4"></span>, <span id="state4"></span> <span id="country4"></span></p>
        <p class="card-text">DUNS# <span id="duns4"></span></p>
        <p class="card-text">CEO: <span id="ceo4"></span></p>
        <a id="riskReport4" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Risk Report</a>
      </div>
```

[image: Expected outcome]

Comment: "but i am struggling with getting the overlay to build the html" - this is too vague, I don't see the problem. Also, [selectionchange](https://devdocs.io/dom_events/selectionchange) may be a better event to listen to.

Comment: I am wanting something like the following to be used so that i can add the data from an api call to it.

when writing the html to a function it i can not get it to populate in overlay
function writeHTMLasJS() {
  document.write('<div>');
  document.write('      <div class="card">');
  document.write('      <div class="card-body">');
  document.write('        <h5 class="card-title" id="supplier1"></h5>');
}

Comment: Don't use document.write, use innerHTML like you do currently or even better, find an existing js library that shows tooltips/bubbles.